# How do you transform a map into another map with Terraform 0.12?

Tags: terraform

This is due to crappy default behavior of the AWS provider wrt ASGs.

I had to resort to doing this:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15226

```
data "null_data_source" "asg-tags" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.tags))}"
  inputs = {
    key                 = "${element(keys(var.tags), count.index)}"
    value               = "${element(values(var.tags), count.index)}"
    propagate_at_launch = "true"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my-group" {
  ....
  tags = ["${data.null_data_source.asg-tags.*.outputs}"]
```

How do I do this with 0.12? I know there is better features for this sort of thing now so I should not have to use the null resource any more but I can't find any 0.12 examples of how to loop over a map and generate a new map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew about dynamic blocks, but didnt think about it enough. This is much easier how. Can just have a list var and use dynamic block right in the resource

```
  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = var.mytags
    content {
      key = tag.key
      value = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }
```